# What is the meaning and usage of “erstwhile”?

Tags: meaning

What is meaning of *erstwhile* and where is it used?  How   can I use this word in real life while texting, talking, and so on?

Comment: Erstwhile is a formal term, use the more common *former* or *one-time*:  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/erstwhile

Comment: @Josh61 You said: *I'd say it is formal and used mainly in writing, but far from disappeared*  and *"it's alive and kicking"* To which I replied it is rarely heard or used etc. (see comments below Candied Orange).  Where in any of these dictionary entries does it say that the term is used mostly in writing. And by the way, a formal term can still be very commonly heard and used. 1) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/erstwhile 2) http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/erstwhile 3) http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/erstwhile?s=t

Comment: Do those dictionaries say it is rarely used or heard? They usually do with rare terms.

Comment: @Andrew Leach- can you please post what OED says about 'erstwhile'? I don't have access to it.

Comment: oed says erstwhile means former http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/erstwhile

Comment: oxforddictionaries.com is not OED: that's oed.com. @josh OED says "adverb: formerly, *archaic*; adjective: former, *literary.*" The latest citation is 1881 for the adverb and 1925 for the adjective, but the entry is long overdue for an update.

Comment: [It's a pity the question has been closed for lack of research, because just looking up the word in a dictionary doesn't tell you how, when or if to use it in text, or everyday speech](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265362/erstwhile-meaning-and-usage-in-english#comment583725_265368). If the OP wishes to reopen the question all he need do is cite one or two definitions from two different dictionaries and then ask: "How and when do I use the term *erstwhile* in real life, in a conversation, if I'm texting, or writing anything."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erstwhile means former, as in, no longer.  It is [archaic](https://www.google.com/search?q=Erstwhile&oq=Erstwhile&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8).  You can use it in real life so long as you're in period dress at a renaissance fair.  Other than that expect people to look at you funny.  Well actually, I can't guarantee they won't do that at the fair either...

Comment: I'd say it is  formal and used mainly in writing, but far from disappeared:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erstwhile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cerstwhile%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ok, at a renaissance fair or as a film noir author.  I still make no guarantees regarding looks.  "Of all the answers to comment on he had to comment on mine...."

Comment: @Josh61 you know as well as I that Ngram does not "show" us how popular or common a single term is. Compare it with any of the suggested synonyms  http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/erstwhile

Comment: @Josh61 please look at Google Books results for "erstwhile" https://www.google.it/search?q=%22erstwhile%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=GFfEVbSLD4vqUq__qcgD#q=%22erstwhile%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=10 It is extremely rare, possibly found in print, but nowadays nobody actually "says" it. I can't upvote this answer because it's a little too flippant, and it ignores the other uses of erstwhile.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - that's not the point I was making, erstwhile is still alive and kicking despite it is not a common term.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - As an adjective ODO doesn't even mention it is formal http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/erstwhile while OLD properly does IMO.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/erstwhile

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't ignore other uses, I contrasted them with one example that might actually make usage appropriate (even if still annoying).  Also, I take my flippancy very seriously.  Calling it "little" is getting personal.  Now, I shall go pout.  Hmmf.

Comment: @Mari-LouA . I do run into this term often enough not to have to resort to a dictionary to check what it means. It is not common, it is just formal.

Comment: @Josh61 please look at how **erstwhile** is used in [Google Books 1990-2000](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22erstwhile%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=GFfEVbSLD4vqUq__qcgD#q=%22erstwhile%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=20) and then tell me "it's alive and kicking". Archaic does not mean *obsolete*, although perhaps "rarely used or heard" might be a more accurate way of describing it. Candied Orange is a native speaker, trust his judgement.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - you mean the story about the renaissance fair...

Comment: @Josh61 a tux is formal,  a powdered wig is formal.  Being archaic isn't about being formal.  It's about being out of style.  https://www.google.com/search?q=Erstwhile&oq=Erstwhile&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Josh61  Renaissance fair... I wouldn't go as far back as that, I could imagine Charles Darwin using this expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You misunderstand renaissance fairs.  They are not about historical accuracy.  They are a form of counter culture.  The fact that erstwhile is still used today doesn't prove that it's in style.  It proves that beatniks and their ilk love to resurrect old things because they're out of style.  The moment it became popular they'd drop it.  So be warned.  Go around using this word and that's who you're making yourself seem like.  Not that there's anything wrong with that...

Comment: I understand, I've watch TBBT too :) I'm not championing "erstwhile" as being current, it is Josh who does. I thought my links and comments were sufficiently clear. It's a pity the question has been closed for lack of research, because just looking up the word in a dictionary doesn't tell you how, when or if to use it in text, or everyday speech.

Comment: can you tell me any simple sentence by using word erstwhile ?

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  "I'm not championing "erstwhile" as being current, it is Josh who does???"  I clearly said, as any dictionary you may look up would tell you, that it is a formal term used mainly in writing. (Does this mean championing its usage as current?). It is a term discussed on the net https://www.google.it/#q=erstwhile+vs+former+ where there is not much hint to being "extinct". Curiously it has an entry also in the super slang UD:  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=erstwhile

Comment: @ ruakh, Josh61, Andrew Leach  i want to ask you that why my question is off the topic ? erstwhile is archaic english word isn't it ?

Comment: I, CandiedOrange, your erstwhile question answerer, will never stoop so low as to recite the word in proper context.  Aw crap I already did.

Comment: Let it be alive until we get aggrandize meaning to erstwhile where oed just say it means former